# `this` is undefined inside an object

Tags: node.js, this

With Nodejs, I am calling a function called `customFunction` which is a mutation from a GrpahQL Resolver. I don't have acces to `this`.

```
import { Mutation } from './mutation/Mutation'
export default {
  Query,
  Mutation,
}
```

then in `Mutation.ts`

```
import { customFunctionMutation } from './customFunctionMutation'
export const Mutation = {
  customFunction: customFunctionMutation.customFunction,
}
```

then in `customFunctionMutation.ts`

```
export const customFunctionMutation = {
  test() {
    console.log('test called')
  },
  async customFunction(parent: any, args: any, ctx: any, info: any) {
    console.log('customFunction init')
    console.log('this', this)
    this.test()
    console.log('customFunction end')
  },
}
```

this is `undefined` and i cannot called the function `test()` which is in the same object

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You separated the method from the object that has the `test` method when you did this:

```
import { customFunction } from './customFunction'
```

So, then when you try to call `customFunction()` it will have no association with the object it is declared inside of and thus it can't reference `this.test()` because `this` will be `undefined`.

FYI, giving the same name to the export and a property on the export is hopelessly confusing to your clients.  Please don't do that.

---

I would suggest fixing it by making your module be independent of how it was called by changing it to no longer use `this`:

```
const moduleObj = {
  test() {
    console.log('test called')
  },
  async customFunction(parent: any, args: any, ctx: any, info: any) {
    console.log('customFunction init')
    console.log('this', this)
    moduleObj.test()
    console.log('customFunction end')
  },
}

export default moduleObj;
```

Then, you can use:

```
import { customFunction } from './customFunction'
```

And, you can then call:

```
customFunction()
```

and it will be able to function properly when called.

Comment: thanks! Agree with you, but here https://javascript.info/object-methods, it says : "Technically, it’s also possible to access the object without this, by referencing it via the outer variable: " .. "…But such code is unreliable. If we decide to copy user to another variable, e.g. admin = user and overwrite user with something else, then it will access the wrong object."

Comment: agreed with your FYI!

Comment: @Alan - Actually, I don't think you could referencing the outer object variable name because you declared the function with the same name which hides the higher scoped version.  Yes, you could change the name and then access it which is essentially what I offered - I just make it a little more obvious.

Comment: Thanks! It is what I am going to do. I'm a bit concerned because I have been using this exact same pattern with 'this' in my code, and the same type of import and it worked. I still did not get why sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.. I will do more deep dive.

Comment: @Alan - If you import the parent object and you call the function as a property of the parent object, then `this` will work.  So, perhaps that's what you were doing.

Comment: Here you have a small video where `this` is not undefined. It is the same Pattern as customFunction. https://app.usebubbles.com/d5ccef0f-1d8b-4889-bb10-1c72e32c1962 Really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

Probably one of these could work:

```
import { customFunction } from './customFunction'
export const Mutation = {
  customFunction: customFunction.customFunction.bind(customFunction),
}
```

or

```
import { customFunction } from './customFunction'
export const Mutation = customFunction
```

or

```
import { customFunction } from './customFunction'
export const Mutation = {
  customFunction: function functionName(...parameters) { return customFunction.customFunction(...parameters); },
}
```

Comment: The first1 works well! Thanks. For the second, how would you do if you have to add many objects inside the object Mutation? (example customFunction1 and customFunction2)?